# A variant of Nelson-Hadwiger Problem on the chromatic number of the plane

Tags: discrete-geometry, graph-colorings

The famous Nelson-Hadwiger problem asks about the chromatic number of the graph $G$, with the vertex set $V(G)={\mathbb R}^2$ where $a_1=(x_1,y_1), a_2=(x_2,y_2) \in V(G) \ $ form an edge iff $a_1-a_2$ has Euclidean length $1$, or equivalently, $$(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=1.$$ It is relatively easy to see that the chromatic number is one of the number $4,5,6,7$, and there is a vast literature on this and some closely related problems.

The question I have come across is the following: consider the graph $G'$ with the same vertex set $V$, but assume that $a_1=(x_1,y_1), a_2=(x_2,y_2) \in V \ $  form an edge iff
$$ (x_1-x_2)^2-(y_1-y_2)^2=1.$$ What is the chromatic number of this graph? Since the set $x^2-y^2=1$ misses a neighborhood of $0$, it is clear that $ \chi(G') \le \aleph_0$. But I cannot even show that $ \chi( G')$ is finite. 
I would be thankful if anyone can help by an idea of pointing me to any existing literature on this question.

Comment: For what it's worth, in proposition 6.5 of my unpublished note [“The Hadwiger-Nelson problem over certain fields”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.07023v1) I prove that $\chi(G')\geq 3$ (which is easy, and probably not original).

Comment: "It is relatively easy to see that the chromatic number is one of the number $4,5,6,7$...." As readers probably know, in 2018, Aubrey de Grey ruled out $4$, 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385

Answer (score 7):

It's apparently an open problem as to whether it's finite:

[Olga Kosheleva & Vladik Kreinovich, “On chromatic numbers of space-times: open problems” (UTEP Technical Report UTEP-CS-08-42)](https://scholarworks.utep.edu/cs_techrep/124/)