# Lorentzian (=Minkowskian) Hadwiger-Nelson problem: is the chromatic number finite?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, graph-colorings

**Background:** Some years ago, I collected a number of thoughts and partial results (which, based on Soifer's *Mathematical coloring* book, I believed were new) on the [Hadwiger-Nelson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) in [a note](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.07023) that I then submitted for publication.  The referee pointed to me that many of my results had been obtained previously by G. Eric Moorhouse (of U. Wyoming) in [a much earlier note](https://web.archive.org/web/20170419134628/http://www.uwyo.edu/moorhouse/pub/chromatic.pdf) that he never published but made available online.  The referee encouraged me to still do something with my own note but, while I tried to figure out how to salvage it it, Aubrey de Grey made [a decisive progress](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385) on the lower bound in the H-N problem which rendered most of my remaining results uninteresting or irrelevant, so I gave up on this publication.  However, there remains one question which I raised in my note (see §6), which I hoped to draw attention to, and which I will now ask here (perhaps in the hope that, like everything else in this note, it has been studied and closed by someone else):

> Consider the (undirected) graph whose vertices are the points of $\mathbb{R}^2$, with an edge between $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ whenever $(x'-x)^2 - (y'-y)^2 = 1$.  Let $\chi_{\mathrm{L}}$ (possibly $+\infty$) be its chromatic number.  What can be said about $\chi_{\mathrm{L}}$?  And more specifically:
>
> **Main question**: is $\chi_{\mathrm{L}}<+\infty$?

**Comments:** This question is the natural “Lorentzian” (or should I say “Minkowskian”) analogue of the Euclidean H-N problem (which concerns the edge relation $(x'-x)^2 + (y'-y)^2 = 1$ instead), and based on Sylvester's classification of quadratic forms over $\mathbb{R}$, it is cleared that the chromatic number of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with edge relation $q((x',y')-(x,y)) = 1$ for any non-degenerate quadratic form $q$ will reduce wither to the classical (Euclidean) H-N problem or to the Lorentzian one I just mentioned.  An easy lower bound is $\chi_{\mathrm{L}} \geq 3$ because the graph contains odd cycles, even though, unlike in the Euclidean case, it does not contain any triangle (see proposition 6.5 in my aforementioned note).  I could not find any coloring with finitely many colors, though, and I faintly suspect that $\chi_{\mathrm{L}} = +\infty$ (and de Grey's Euclidean result tends to reinforce that suspicion).

A somewhat related problem that I can also mention is that of finding the chromatic number of $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the edge relation $(x'-x)^2 + (y'-y)^2 = 1$ (clearly, both the Euclidean and Lorentzian versions of the chromatic number of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are lower bounds on that of $\mathbb{C}^2$).  Of course, we can also consider various generalizations for $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ or other fields with various quadratic forms (but if we already can't color $\mathbb{R}^2$ with finitely many colors for the Lorentzian quadratic form, we also can't color $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ and these questions are moot).

So, have the above questions been considered in the literature or even in an obscure note published only on the author's web page?

Comment: For completeness of MathOverflow: the present question is pretty much a duplicate of [this other one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/201790/17064).